# Start increment column at begining of month

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, counter, timedelta

thank you in advance for your assistance.

Want set 'Counter' to 1 whenever there is change in month, and increment by 1 until month changes again, and repeat.  Like so:

```
                     A          Month Counter
        2015-10-30  -1.478066   10    21
        2015-10-31  -1.562437   10    22
        2015-11-01  -0.292285   11    1
        2015-11-02  -1.581140   11    2
        2015-11-03  0.603113    11    3
        2015-11-04  -0.543563   11    4

In [1]: import pandas as pd
          import numpy as np

In [2]: dates = pd.date_range('20151030',periods=6)

In [3]: df =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),index=dates,columns=list('A'))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:             A
        2015-10-30  -1.478066
        2015-10-31  -1.562437
        2015-11-01  -0.292285
        2015-11-02  -1.581140
        2015-11-03  0.603113
        2015-11-04  -0.543563
```

Tried this, adds 1 to actual month integer:

```
In [5]: df['Month'] = df.index.month

In [6]: df['Counter'] df['Counter']=np.where(df['Month'] <> df['Month'], (1), (df['Month'].shift()+1))

In [7]: df
Out[7]:  A                     Month Counter
        2015-10-30  -1.478066   10  NaN
        2015-10-31  -1.562437   10  11
        2015-11-01  -0.292285   11  11
        2015-11-02  -1.581140   11  12
        2015-11-03  0.603113    11  12
        2015-11-04  -0.543563   11  12
```

Tried datetime, getting closer:

```
In[8]:  from datetime import timedelta

In[9]:  df['Counter'] = df.index + timedelta(days=1)
Out[9]:     A                      Month    Counter
            2015-10-30  -0.478066   11  2015-10-31
            2015-10-31  -1.562437   10  2015-11-01
            2015-11-01  -0.292285   11  2015-11-02
            2015-11-02  -1.581140   11  2015-11-03
            2015-11-03  0.603113    11  2015-11-04
            2015-11-04  -0.543563   11  2015-11-05
```

Latter give me the date, but not my counter.  New to python, so any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Edit, extending df to periods=300 to include over 12 months of data:

```
In[10]: dates = pd.date_range('19971002',periods=300)
In[11]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300,1),index=dates,columns=list('A'))
In[12]: df['Counter'] = df.groupby(df.index.month).cumcount()+1
In[13]: df.head()
Out[13]             A          Counter
        1997-09-29  -0.875468   20
        1997-09-30   1.498145   21
        1997-10-02   0.141262   1
        1997-10-03   0.581974   2
        1997-10-04   0.581974   3

In[14]: df[250:]
Out[14]             A          Counter
        1998-09-29  -0.875468   20
        1998-09-30   1.498145   21
        1998-10-01   0.141262   24
        1998-10-02   0.581974   25
```

Desired results:

```
Out[13]             A          Counter
        1997-09-29  -0.875468   20
        1997-09-30   1.498145   21
        1997-10-02   0.141262   1
        1997-10-03   0.581974   2
        1997-10-04   0.581974   3
```

Code works fine (Out[13] above), seems to be once data goes beyond 12 months counter keeps on incrementing +1 instead of setting back to 1([Out 14] above.  Also, getting tricky here, random date generator includes weekend, my data only has weekday data.  Hope that helps me help you to help me better.  Thank you!

Comment: Your desired output is not consistent with your input. The `dates` begin on `1997-10-02`, but the desired output has dates beginning on `1997-09-29`.

Comment: Are you sure `df['Counter'] = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).cumcount()+1` is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`groupby/cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) to assign a cumulative count to each group:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 300
dates = pd.date_range('19971002', periods=N, freq='B')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 1),index=dates,columns=list('A'))
df['Counter'] = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).cumcount()+1
print(df.loc['1998-09-25':'1998-10-05'])
```

yields

```
                   A  Counter
1998-09-25 -0.511721       19
1998-09-28  1.912757       20
1998-09-29 -0.988309       21
1998-09-30  1.277888       22
1998-10-01 -0.579450        1
1998-10-02 -2.486014        2
1998-10-05  0.728789        3
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works perfect for 12 months and then counter jumps from 21 to 24 (instead of 1) on 13th month, and first day of month for 14th month in sequence gets set to 20.  Counter number gets very large at end of data set. Thanks again, closer than ever, suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to group by both the year and the month? In that case use `df.groupby(df.index.year, df.index.month).cumcount()+1`

Comment: Just by month, code you posted works fine for first 12 instances month changes, however at month 13, counter is set to 24 and second day of 13th month counter increments by 1 to 25,  and inaccurate for rest of data set.  There are over 12 years of data.  Sugesstions?  Thxs again!

Comment: Can you post data which shows the problem and the desired result? I don't even understand what you mean by "month 13" when `df.index.month` only returns numbers between 1 and 12, and you say you do not want to group by year and month.